# How to express that two equivalence relations can setoid rewrite across each other (Coq)

Tags: coq

I am looking for a way to express that two equivalence relations are compatible and can (setoid) rewrite across each other. As an example here's an ordinary proof I wrote that a left inverse implies injectivity

```
Definition injection {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) :=
  forall a1 a2, f a1 = f a2 -> a1 = a2.

Definition left_inverse {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) :=
  exists finv: B -> A, forall a: A, finv (f a) = a.

Lemma injection_left_inverse {A B : Type}: forall (f: A -> B), left_inverse f -> injection f.
Proof.
  unfold left_inverse, injection.
  intros.
  destruct H as [finv H'].
  assert (H'': finv (f a1) = a1) by (apply H').
  rewrite <- H''.
  rewrite H0.
  rewrite H'.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I'd like to extended to something like this:

```
Definition injection' {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (Arel: relation A) (Brel: relation B) :=
  forall a1 a2, Brel (f a1) (f a2) -> Arel a1 a2.

Definition left_inverse' {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (Arel: relation A) (Brel: relation B) :=
  exists finv: B -> A, forall a: A, Arel (finv (f a)) a.

Lemma injection_left_inverse' {A B : Type}: forall (f: A -> B) (Arel: relation A) (Brel: relation B), 
  left_inverse' f Arel Brel -> injection' f Arel Brel.
Proof.
Admitted.
```

where `Arel` and `Brel` are some equivalence relations that critically *are potentially different but compatible in a way that they should be able to rewrite across each other*.

This last part is what I don't know how to express. For a single equivalence relation, I know that I can use `Add Parametric Relation` to allow rewriting, but I don't know how to express that these relations are compatible. I assume it is some use of `Proper`, but I haven't been able to figure it out exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As additional hypotheses to the theorem, you need `Equivalence Arel`, which implies `Proper (Arel ==> Arel ==> iff) Arel` (so `Arel` can rewrite *under itself*) and `Proper (Arel ==> Brel) f` (that `f` is actually a well-defined function out of "`A/Arel`" into "`B/Brel`"). Further, you similarly need to modify the definition `left_inverse'` to say that the presented left inverse is in fact a well defined function.

```
(* IMO you should also put Arel and Brel before f in the parameter list *)
Definition left_inverse' {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (Arel: relation A) (Brel: relation B) :=
  exists finv: B -> A, Proper (Brel ==> Arel) finv /\ forall a: A, Arel (finv (f a)) a.
```

The proof should now go through.

- That you need to assume (some of) the relations involved are actually equivalences should not be surprising.
- In general, for any object `x : T` in a setoid-based proof, you also need a proof that it is actually a "well-defined" element of that type, which means you need `Proper Trel x`, where `Trel` is some relation that follows the structure of `T`. In this case, over the course of the proof you have the objects `f : A -> B` and  `finv : B -> A`, so you need `Proper (A ==> B) f, Proper (B ==> A) finv`. For elements `x : A`, you actually get `Proper Arel x` from reflexivity of `Arel`.